# Type Error: Integer is required - Pygame , Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm following a tutorial online , creating a button for pygame.

```
textSurf,textRect = smallfont.render(msg,color,size)
```

I've just started learning pygame yesterday.

I met with an error stating that `"Type Error: Integer is require"`. What does this mean? Can someone help me out?

The error is located at  `textSurf,textRect = smallfont.render(msg,color,size)`

Answer (score 2):

You're calling

```
textSurf,textRect = smallfont.render(msg,color,size)
```

...with a color as second parameter and "Small" as the third parameter, however the second and third parameter to `render` should be an antialiasing flag and a color in that order.

Since you have a function right above that translates "small" to the correct parameters to render, what you want is most likely;

```
textSurf,textRect = textObj(msg,color,size)
```

(although watch out for the casing of "Small" vs. "small")

Comment: why is my screen blank(black)?

Comment: @stack If you didn't replace "Small" in the default value to `textToButton ` with "small" (exactly matching your switch in textObj) nothing is rendered since it doesn't match a font size. If you fixed that and it still doesn't give any output, is there any error message displayed?

Comment: no error message is given. the output is just blank(black)screen

Comment: @stack Seems you're rendering the text in black, so if the background is black you may want to pass another color to `textToButton("Start",black,240,200,120,50)`.

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682471/output-is-blank-and-it-not-responding-pygame-python-2-7  , I just posted